# How to generate a ui_Foo.h file from a Qt Foo.ui in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, qt

Is there a way to automatically generate the user interface header `ui_Foo.h` file from a Qt designer `Foo.ui` file? (My Visual Studio Solution already has one such `ui*.h` file that was generated when I first created the solution.)

**Edit/solution**:
What I "forgot" to do was to add the ui file to the ("Form Files" tab of the) solution.

Comment: It's been a while since I used QT, but if you use the Qt visual studio add-in you should be able to do so from the right-click option of the file, or simply by building the project.

Comment: @zennehoy's options is indeed the easiest (and could be an answer). In addition to that though, you could also create a custom build rule for the file and call UIC with the appropriate parameters. (Or go the CMake route and have everything set up for you automagically).

Comment: @Bart I haven't used QT in a few years, so I wasn't sure it still worked that way, but apparently it does, so I added an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used QT in a while, but if things haven't changed completely, the Qt visual studio add-in should enable you to compile the .ui file from the right-click menu, or automatically detect changes in the file and compile when building the  project.